# How to stream a video using python and opencv without twilio?

Tags: python, opencv, flask, video-streaming, twilio

I know that video streaming is possible with python using flask framework. But as twilio is a paid platform, is there any other platforms which can be freely used for video streaming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out this blog written by miguel to develop a video steaming platform using flask.
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask

The theory is explained pretty well here and i personally recommend it.
If you want to some recognition or CV stuff you can also checkout tutorial by PyImageSearch.

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/09/02/opencv-stream-video-to-web-browser-html-page/

I think this tutorial is more relevant for you but if you are new to python you may find this a bit overwhelming.

Comment: Both the blog and tutorial says the basics to stream the video. But how to access camera in remote server if we stream a video over internet?

Comment: The tutorial mentioned in the pyimagesearch site is working but the video is not loading in the browser. The html file index.html also loaded correctly.

Comment: Is there any restrictions to install flask like it should be installed on the same folder which python is installed or opencv is installed?